# SSIS - Send mail task not triggered after precedence constraint

Tags: variables, ssis, constraints, type-conversion

The `Send mail task` in my SSIS (based on Visual Studio 2008) package (CodaRawDataUpload.dtsx) **is not triggered** (it does not turn green, yellow or red at all).

SSIS Control Flow
[image]

The SQL inside the "`Row Check`" command returns either `0` or `1` and is defined as an `int`. The result `rows_identical` was defined as a variable with `Int32` datatype.
[image]

The SQL looks like this:

```
DECLARE 
@current_month DATETIME, 
@current_year DATETIME, 
@current_year_final AS INT, 
@previous_period_final VARCHAR(2),
@test_period AS VARCHAR (2),
@previous_period_final_2 VARCHAR(2)

SET @current_month = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()),0)
SET @current_year = DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR,0,GETDATE()),0)
SET @current_year_final = CASE WHEN LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) = '01' THEN LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@current_year,112),4)-1 ELSE LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@current_year,112),4) END
SET @previous_period_final = CASE
    WHEN CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) AS INT) - 1 BETWEEN 10 AND 11 THEN  CAST(CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) AS INT) - 1 AS VARCHAR)  -- Type Varchar
    WHEN CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),3),1) AS INT) - 1 BETWEEN 1  AND 8  THEN '0' + CAST(CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),3),1) AS INT) - 1 AS VARCHAR)
    WHEN CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) AS INT) - 1 = 9 THEN '09'
    WHEN      LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) = '01'          THEN '12'
    ELSE 'Invalid formula' END
SET @previous_period_final_2 = CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(),112),4),2) AS INT) - 1 

select CAST(CAST(case when count_rows_raw = count_rows_facts then 1 else 0 end as bit)as int) as rows_identical 
--,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(CAST(CAST(case when count_rows_raw = count_rows_facts then 1 else 0 end as bit)as int),'BaseType') -- ### EXCELLENT WAY TO RETRIEVE DATATYPE ###
from
(
 select
    (
     select SUM(#rows_facts) as #rows_facts from 
        (                                               
         select COUNT(ID) as #rows_facts, 'finalized_entries_facts_table' as type from facts_reporting where DateID in (select DateID from dim_date as date  
                                                left join dim_month month on month.MonthID = date.MonthID 
                                                left join dim_year year on year.YearID = date.YearID
                                                where year.YearName = CAST(@current_year_final AS Varchar) and month = @previous_period_final_2)
                                                and   SourceID IN (select SourceID from dbo.dim_source where Source = 'CODA')
union
         select COUNT(ID) as #rows_facts, 'missing_entries_facts_table' as type from missing_ids_CODA_raw where DateID in (select DateID from dim_date as date  
                                                left join dim_month month on month.MonthID = date.MonthID 
                                                left join dim_year year on year.YearID = date.YearID
                                                where year.YearName = CAST(@current_year_final AS Varchar) and month = @previous_period_final_2)
                                                and   SourceID IN (select SourceID from dbo.dim_source where Source = 'CODA')                                       
        ) as rows
    ) as count_rows_facts,
    (
     select COUNT(doccode) as #rows_raw from CodaRaw where yr_period = CAST(@current_year_final AS Varchar)+'/'+CAST(@previous_period_final_2 AS Varchar)
    ) as count_rows_raw
)
as row_checks
```

In the SQL task settings I have used this variable as follows:
[image]

As for the Precedence Constraint Editor I have tried both (value = 0 or value = 1) but the send mail task is never triggered:

[image]

Why? What is the problem here?

EDIT: Added screen when adding breakpoint
[image]

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your constraint.  So probably something is happening that you are not aware of.

Comment: Do you have any idea where I could look at? I don't really know where to start. The only which comes to my mind would be to exchange the send mail task with something else and see if that task won't be triggered as well.

Comment: Why do you say it is not being triggered?   Does it never turn red or green in the debugger, or does it just not send an email?

Comment: One more question: Regarding the "Variables" window.. what exactly does the column "Value" mean there. I haven't actively defined this and used the default setting "0". Does this cause any problems?

Comment: It never turns red, green or yellow at all. The SQL task turns green and then nothing happens...

Comment: The value in the variables window is the starting (ie default) value of the variable.   It doesn't cause any problems if you set the value to something else during the package run.  Put a breakpoint on the post-execute event of your SQL task and use a watch to look at the value of your variable.   I guess it's not being set to 1 for some reason.

Comment: I have edited what my screen shows when I am doing this. What does this tell me?

Comment: Not enough yet.   While you're at the breakpoint (your screenshot), click on Debug > Windows > Locals, and it should show you the current running value of your variable.   And while I'm thinking of it, verify that your Execute SQL task has "single row" selected for the result set.

Comment: A null return might cause this problem.

Comment: @Tab Alleman: That's it! For some reason it shows that the `variable` has a value of 10 which is surprising as I have defined it as a 1 or 0 event (see SQL above) only. How come that it turns a `1` into a `10`? Does this have something to do with the datatype I chose for the variable in `SSIS` which is `Int32`? Adjusting my precedence constraint to this new value triggers the mail task but I would like to understand the cause of the problem.

Comment: I don't see anything in what you've included in your question that could cause your variable to have a value of 10.   It's not the variable type.   `Int32` is fine.   It must be some part of the sql or package that you aren't showing, but I can't imagine what it could be.